# npm error-npm not found in terminal

Tags: node.js

Please help me to clear this error

```
Apples-Mac-mini:bin apple$ curl -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0    244      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   471
100  6711  100  6711    0     0    431      0  0:00:15  0:00:15 --:--:--  5456
sh: line 20: npm-install-3294.sh: Permission denied
sh: npm-install-3294.sh: No such file or directory
rm: npm-install-3294.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

Note the `sudo` in front. The errors you get are due to installer trying to copy files to system folders, requiring administrative permissions.

Also, you do not actually need to install NPM, as it is included in latest Node.js versions.
To install Node.js on MacOS, refer to [their official site](http://nodejs.org/download/).

Comment: Thanks Friend Alandarev

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, run sh using sudo:

```
$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```